# Can i check to see if the iPhone is docked?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I wish for my app to act differently when the phone is docked or otherwise connected to the computer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I couldn't find anything offhand about whether it's docked, but if you look at the [UIDevice class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) you'll find the `batteryState` property. If you enable battery monitoring in your app, you can check to see if the property is set to `UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged`, implying the device *isn't* docked. If it's another value (`UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging` or `UIDeviceBatteryStateFull`), the phone is connected to power.

Note this doesn't guarantee there's a computer at the other end; it could just as easily be a power adapter into a wall or other USB-powered device.

Answer (score 0):

You can also monitor accessory connection changes using **EAAccessoryManager** class method '**registerForLocalNotifications**' and adding observer for notifications **EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification**, **EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification**.for more reference see apple docs [EAAccessoryManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessoryManager_class/Reference/Reference.html)